# Render a .js controller request as html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

I have a `before_filter` in my Rails app that sends users to `login_url` if they are logged out when they submit a request (in either html or js format).

I would like my `format.js` to produce an identical result to `format.html`, in the following case to render the view with the 'notice' layout. How can I do this?

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
  format.html{ render :layout => "notice" }
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can force the usable formats like this :

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js   { render :layout => "notice", :formats => [:html] }
  format.html { render :layout => "notice" }
end
```

EDIT:

What you need is some part of the document being replaced by the response. This is done by responding with a javascript that does the job:

In your controller :

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
  format.html { render :layout => "notice" }
end
```

In your login.js view :

```
$('#whatever').html('<%= escape_javascript( render :login, formats: [ :html ]) %>')
```

... or something similar

Comment: Hi, thanks for your note. Your solution stops me from getting an error, but I still have the problem that if someone submits an AJAX request, nothing appears to happen. The server thinks it has done its job but the user doesn't see anything different. How do I convert the JS request such that the login page appears to the user?

Comment: In this case, the response must be a script including your layout contents (see my edit):